# Is there a way to run Vim with a custom vimfiles

Tags: vim

I have my Vim configuration in my `$HOME/vimfiles`. Sometimes, however, I want to try out modified configurations without messing up my standard setup. Is it possible to make vim look at a different `vimfiles` directory for startup files?

The easiest option would probably be to set `$HOME` to a different value and run Vim, but that can interfere with other software (I'm on Windows so it's not as bad as for Unix users, but I use Msys for some of my work, and setting `$HOME` there will affect other stuff).

Comment: I'd ask this question at [Super User](http://superuser.com) rather than Stack Overflow.

Comment: It sounds like you want to try out something temporarily...why can't you just set HOME temporarily, in a cmd.exe window, and then launch Vim? Or does your "try out modified configurations" task last longer than one or two tries?

Comment: The problem with setting HOME is that (particularly in an msys environment) it affects other things - i.e., it isn't Vim-specific. And generally it'll be something I want to use for a day or so, to see how it feels.

Answer (score 1):

```
  -u {vimrc}  Use  the  commands in the file {vimrc} for initializations.  All the
                   other initializations are skipped.  Use this to edit a special  kind
                   of files.  It can also be used to skip all initializations by giving
                   the name "NONE".  See ":help initialization"  within  vim  for  more
                   details.
```

e.g. I have a very basic vimrc file, saved as `~/base.vimrc`, and an alias:

```
kent$ alias bvi
bvi='vim -u ~/base.vimrc'
```

Comment: Does that also set the runtimepath to use vimfiles from that location as well (i.e., is runtimepath set based on the location of the alternative vimrc? Specifically does this *omit* $HOME/vimfiles from vimrc?